# WebProvisioned Event Receiver Firing Twice

Tags: event-receivers, provisioning

I am creating sites and subsites with object model from a console app. And what i realized is, it fires twice for every newly created subsite. I checked from Sharepoint Manager if the event receiver is registered twice, but no there are no multiple registrations. So what can cause the WebProvisioned event firing twice?

Edit: I have found a blog article that says the webprovisioned event is firing twice, and the author also does not know why.
[the article](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2010/09/webprovisioned-event-receiver-practical.html)

> One other interesting “feature” (a rather peculiar one) is that when I tested my sample “Site” scoped WebProvisioned receiver it got called twice for one and the same site (no idea yet if this is an issue with my dev environment only or it is something by design). This is not the case for “Web” scoped WebProvisioned receivers.

Comment: Is you last question solved ? Was my answer helpful ?

Comment: yes, thanks. i marked it as answer. what about current problem?do you have any idea?

Comment: To realise the solution to this we would need a code sample, of course please edit your post and include one with your addresses and file names taken out and replaced by place-holder names

Comment: The code is real huge.. But As i know this kind of problem may be faced, for example in ItemUpdating events, when the current item is updated in the Updating event receiver. But here in my situation, a site cannot be provisioned/created twice. This is not like ItemUpdating event.

Comment: @ozdogan code will help to solve the issue!

Comment: posting here 500 lines of code? :)

Comment: Well it will be the surrounding code blocks, you can just comment out the gubbings and put a quick statement of what it does.

Comment: ok then, i will put the code tomorrow when i go back to work. but what i do in WebProvisioned event is; arranging masterpage inheritance, creating page in Pages library, setting it the as the welcome page, and some other customizations. Anything comes to your mind to be the cause for this twice-firing?